# READ RDF File in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a file which it's format is ***RDF***. How can i read this file in matlab. Can we convert it to ***xml*** format.

Is there any matlab method to read ***RDF***?.

Comment: If your RDF is not XML, what serialization is used instead?

Comment: RDF can have [multiple meanings](https://fileinfo.com/extension/rdf). Please clarify which one.